# Sharepoint List with Two views and two Edit forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list of projects with a related list of fields and that page works as intended.  I made a second view of that list that just shows a subsection of that list.  When I click the edit button on the second view I'd like to have an edit form that only has the fields from the parsed down view.  I made a 2nd edit form that has that data but I can't find where I can change the URL for the edit button.

[image: The item in red, how do I change that URL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want two separate edit forms you'll need to create a custom way to access the second editform2.aspx. There's no direct way to change the "built in" button to navigate to a different edit form per view.

Here's what I would do...

1. Add a script editor to the second view (that uses the alternate edit form)
2. Add javascript that effectively "finds" the edit buttons in the current view and replaces the onclick/href value to use editform2.aspx instead of the default.

If you need help with that there's plenty of resource for jquery around. It's as simple as (pseudo code):

```
$('find your buttons').onclick(navigate to editform2.aspx)
```

EDIT:

I should also mention that if you do something that causes a "postback" on the list view that would re-render it (sort/filter/page) it will reset the buttons. So you'll need to tap into the "after ajax" event using the following:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function() { rebind your buttons here again });
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to modify the URL of the edit or new item

what you have to do is to create an action rule to redirect the users to a different infopath edit view.

you have to do this during the load

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit?  I feel like I'm close to understanding but missing a piece.

Comment: I am using sharepoint lists and views to load the data, i'm not using repeating tables on InfoPath.   That would be one way of going about it, but I was hoping to maintain the same styling throughout the site.

Comment: the only way you can have different forms for a new item is by using content types. 

depending on the selected content type the user will see the different fields

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this using SharePoint Designer, Open the site in Sharepoint Designer and Navigate to the list from the left hand navigation.

Then On the List, you see the `editForm.aspx` where you can modify the URL.